# Java checking for running process

Tags: java, process, processlist

I want my java programm to "link" with other programms. So when a certain processes are running my programm should react. I know already how to search for the process in the systems processlist however I am curious if there is a better way to check for that than having a loop searching the whole process list every second.

Comment: I don’t know what “link” means, but the short answer is no, there is no way to be notified of new system processes in Java, without adding your own native code.

Comment: ok thx :) that's all I needed to know ^^